# Does anybody know the name to this British tune?

Tags: military, colonial-america, north-america, french-revolution

Does anybody know the name to [this British tune](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5KIRt_aYjiQ)? The march is from the [show called George Washington](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Washington_(miniseries)) (1984 mini-series).

Comment: Not enough for an answer, but the [soundtrack](https://www.soundtrack.net/album/george-washington/) was composed by [Laurence Rosenthal](http://www.intrada.net/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4076). You could try to figure out how the tracks on the soundtrack mesh with [part 1](https://www.paleycenter.org/collection/item/?q=&p=1&item=B:60510).

Comment: Just researching British marching songs from the era brings up [The British Grenadiers song](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_British_Grenadiers).  I can't tell for sure,  but the basic tune sounds similar to me.

Comment: They sound quite different to me.  I've known the British Grenadiers for 50+ years, and they are not the same!  If it is an original (and not a composition from Laurence Rosenthal) it sounds more of a folk dance tune to me, the sort of thing I'd expect to hear a Morris side playing.  BTW, the snippet in the WP article is taken quite slowly for performance, normally it's played significantly faster. See [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7EA6zxj2e-U) from about 1:30 onwards.

Comment: @Martin Thanks your your comment. I found the song. It's called York Fusiliers. See [here](https://youtu.be/doZzqk-bUJQ).

Comment: @shoover Would you know where to find the whole soundtrack of George Washington to listen for free on youtube?

Comment: @JeremyAbrams You can self answer your question so anyone else curious about the fife and drum music from that era will find your answer. Comments caneventually be deleted.

Comment: ...in fact, I just deleted two of them. Yes, please write an answer to this effect and accept it, if you believe you have found the answer.